# How to only update some fields, when using jOOQ's batch loader with onDuplicateKeyUpdate?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

Is it possible to only update some fields when a duplicate is found, using jOOQ's `batchAll()` loader? Similar to how `onDublicateKeyUpdate()` can be used for single records: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-on-duplicate-key/.

The code I want to change, to only update one field when there's a duplicate:

```
dsl.loadInto(TABLE)
        .batchAll()
        .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
        .loadRecords(records)
        .fields(TABLE.fields())
        .execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible with the [`Loader` API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/), but you can use ordinary batching of individual statements either programmatically using the [batch API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/batch-execution/) or maybe even using a [batched connection](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/batched-connection/), which collects all of your JDBC statements and delays there execution until a batch can be executed:

```java
dsl.batched(c -> {
    for (Record record : records) {
        c.dsl().insertInto(TABLE)
               .set(record)
               .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
               .set(TABLE.FIELD_OF_INTEREST, record.get(TABLE.FIELD_OF_INTEREST))
               .execute(); // Actual execution is delayed until the end of the lambda
    }
}); // Now, all collected statements are batched together
```